# Linear Algebra: Find the Basis of Ker and Im

Tags: linear-algebra

this is the question in question. I imagine it's not actually that hard or complex but I can't really find any other examples similar so I want to run it by you guys. I think the first step is to make the function equal to 0 and solve for a, b, c and d in terms of s and t and then just run it against the definitions of basis, but would anyone do anything different? Thanks for any help or advice in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuuCM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$Ker(T)=\{(a,b,c,d)\in \Bbb R^4\;:\; T(a,b,c,d)=0x^3+0x^2+0x+0\}$$

$$=\{(a,b,c,d): a-b=b-c=c-d=d-a=0\}$$

$$=\{a(1,1,1,1):a\in \Bbb R\}$$

$$=Span(1,1,1,1)$$

Comment: Ah thank you! I can use the span to check the basis, this really helps. Thanks so much!